# Postgres Error running query on database: Could not detect default username

Tags: postgresql, go, docker, docker-compose

Hi I am trying to monitor postgres SQL with Prometheus. For this purpose I am using this exporter https://github.com/wrouesnel/postgres_exporter

I am starting the exporter in my `docker-compose.yml` like this:

```
  exporter-postgres:
    image: wrouesnel/postgres_exporter
    ports:
      - 9113:9113
    environment:
      - DATA_SOURCE_NAME="postgresql://user:pass@localhost:5432/?sslmode=disable"
```

When the exporter is trying to access the database errors like this are thrown:

```
Error running query on database: pg_stat_database pg: Could not detect default username. Please provide one explicitly. file="postgres-exporter.go" line=490
```

and

```
Error scanning runtime variable: pg_stat_database pg: Could not detect default username. Please provide one explicitly. file="postgres-exporter.go" line=464
```

I am not really sure what this message could mean. Also I am not really sure if the issues originates in my docker-compose file, or the exporter.

The lines which throw the error in the `postgres-exporter.go` are:

```
// Use SHOW to get the value
row := db.QueryRow(fmt.Sprintf("SHOW %s;", columnName))

var val interface{}
err := row.Scan(&val)
if err != nil {
    log.Errorln("Error scanning runtime variable:", columnName, err)
    continue
}
```

and

```
query, er := queryOverrides[namespace]
if er == false {
    query = fmt.Sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s;", namespace)
}

// Don't fail on a bad scrape of one metric
rows, err := db.Query(query)
if err != nil {
    log.Println("Error running query on database: ", namespace, err)
    e.error.Set(1)
    return
}
```

https://github.com/wrouesnel/postgres_exporter/blob/master/postgres_exporter.go

I am thankful for any help!

Edit:

Here is the connection to the database:

```
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", e.dsn)
```

Whereas `e.dsn` is generated like this:

```
dsn := os.Getenv("DATA_SOURCE_NAME")
```

The connection doesn't throw any error

Comment: Can you show the line where you connect the `db`?

Comment: I am assuming you are using a different user name than "user". Perhaps you are using [ParseURL](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#ParseURL) and your connection string is not being generated properly? Also see [this](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/938).

Answer (score 12):

Hey for anyone having a similiar issue in the future:

The problem was this line in the docker-compose.yml

```
 - DATA_SOURCE_NAME="postgresql://user:pass@localhost:5432/?sslmode=disable"
```

Changing it to

```
 - DATA_SOURCE_NAME=postgresql://user:pass@localhost:5432/?sslmode=disable
```

(Without the quotes) made everything work :)